# python 2.7 : TypeError: <__main__.nested_object object at 0x...> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to run the [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) method on a nested class/object and it fails on **TypeError: <__main__.nested_object object at 0x...> is not JSON serializable**

What should I change in my class so I could call json.dumps method with input parameters of an implementation of JSONEncoder?

Here is a very simple code that simulate the problem:

```
class leaf_object(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.value = s

class nested_object(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b_list):
        self.a = a
        self.b_list = b_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = nested_object('a1', [leaf_object('a1.1'),leaf_object('a1.2')])
    import json
    print(json.dumps(obj))
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if an object is nested or not; to encode *any* object that isn't directly mapped to a JSON type you'll need to write additional code to handle the conversion.

Comment: Ok, which code is it? I prefer it will be a method I need ti implement in the object and outside it because I have another place that calls json,dumps on any object it gets

Answer (score 0):

You can use subclass `JSONEncoder` and implement your own custom serialization.so use this code :

```
from json import JSONEncoder

class leaf_object(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.value = s

class nested_object(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b_list):
        self.a = a
        self.b_list = b_list

class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = nested_object('a1', [leaf_object('a1.1'),leaf_object('a1.2')])
    obj=MyEncoder().encode(obj)
    import json
    print(json.dumps(obj))
```

this is the result:

```
"{\"a\": \"a1\", \"b_list\": [{\"value\": \"a1.1\"}, {\"value\": \"a1.2\"}]}"
```

Comment: I wasn't clear - I'm trying to avoid the changing of the json.dumps by changing the nested/leaf_object objects code
BTW, you can in your suggestion you can use the json dumps tis way :
    print(json.dumps(obj,cls=MyEncoder))

Comment: why you dont want to change `json.dump` ? so you can change the obj before, as i update the answer ?... if you want another ways you can see similar questions !